# Nexus 10 Problem restoring Android

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

new Nexus 10. Tried Ubuntu-Touch over the weekend and now trying to restore Android, but it appears to be hanging at the "sending 'system'" stage.

What am I doing wrong? Here is the dump:

```
xxx@yyyyy:~/Downloads/mantaray-jdq39$ ./flash-all.sh
erasing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.028s]
finished. total time: 0.028s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  0.098s]
finished. total time: 0.098s
erasing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.027s]
finished. total time: 0.027s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.148s]
finished. total time: 0.148s
******** Did you mean to fastboot format this partition?
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  0.537s]
finished. total time: 0.537s
sending 'bootloader' (1280 KB)...
OKAY [  0.181s]
writing 'bootloader'...
OKAY [  0.147s]
finished. total time: 0.328s
rebooting into bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
finished. total time: 0.001s
archive does not contain 'boot.sig'
archive does not contain 'recovery.sig'
archive does not contain 'system.sig'
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: MANTALJ12
Baseband Version.....: no modem
Serial Number........: R32D800DG9N
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.001s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.001s]
sending 'boot' (4608 KB)...
OKAY [  0.618s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.116s]
sending 'recovery' (5108 KB)...
OKAY [  0.688s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.120s]
erasing 'system'...
OKAY [  0.149s]
sending 'system' (522703 KB)...
```

Comment: *I does work, but I haven't tried recently.* Try **kot49h** (4.4.2) instead. There may be backwards compatibility issues going from 'AOSP' **4.4.2** (& Ubuntu Touch) back to **4.2.2** (jdq39).

Comment: I've now tried with kot49h (4.4.2) but it just hangs at the same stage: sending 'system'....

Comment: Update: success at last, after I changed to a shorter USB cable and different USB port (likely to be the cable I suspect....). Thanks for encouraging me to persist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is with either the USB cable or the USB port.